# Raspberry pi Autostart.desktop terminal

Tags: linux, desktop

I'm running a python script that starts with a   autostart.desktop   file

the problem is that i have terminal=true but it doesn't show any terminal but the script is running.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Autostart
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Hidden=false
Exec=sudo python /home/pi/soundsystem.py
StartupNotify=true
```

Is there something wrong in the .desktop file??

Answer (score 0):

The "Terminal" parameter is to run the script in a terminal not display the terminal itself.

In order to display the terminal, you may need to change your exec command to:

```
gnome-terminal -e "sudo python /home/pi/soundsystem.py"
```

Please try this and see if it works. Hope it helps! :)